# Check out my C++ Scrolling Menu and give any tips

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, menu

Right now I have a working scrolling menu, I just wanted to ask if there is anyone to give tips how to compact this because it's a bit "CHUNKY"!
Also I have two extra questions: How can I change it for my
 "Rock,
   Paper,
   Scissors"
to be displayed like "Rock,   Paper",  Scissors"? If you try out my code, you'd see the text is all vertical, can I make it all horizontal? And is there any tips how to make it into a void statement to be used multiple times?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string Menu[3] = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};
int pointer = 0;

while(true)
{
    system("cls");

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
    cout << "Main Menu\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (i == pointer)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 11);
            cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    while(true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
        {
            pointer -= 1;
            if (pointer == -1)
            {
                pointer = 2;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
        {
            pointer += 1;
            if (pointer == 3)
            {
                pointer = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
        {
            switch (pointer)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    cout << "\n\n\nStarting new game...";
                    Sleep(1000);
                } break;
                case 1:
                {
                    cout << "\n\n\nThis is the options...";
                    Sleep(1000);
                } break;
                case 2:
                {
                    return 0;
                } break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    Sleep(150);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<< endl;` adds a new-line character. To print horizontally, print a comma before the menu item, unless it's the first item. I.e - `if (i != 0) cout << ", ";`

Comment: No, that wouldn't be the cause for "Rock, Paper Scissors" becauses it already used commas but it acts like a endl, also is their anyway to compact this "Huge" code? @enhzflep

Comment: So, I take it then that you want the output to be `Rock Paper Scissors`, as opposed to `Rock, Paper, Scissors`?

Comment: Yes! Thats exactly what I want. @enhzflep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of different ways you could go about this. I'd prefer to go about it a different way in my own code,but have tried to write something that was as close to your own code as I could at this hour of the day.

You can re-use the same function for any menu that needs displaying - just give it a different value for the list of strings and the count of the number of strings in that array. Even better - use a `std::vector<string>`.

Rather than hard-code the number of menu items in the main function, I work it out by taking the total size of the array of strings and dividing it by the size of the first element. Since each element gives the same value for sizeof regardless of the length of the string, this allows you to calculate the number of elements in the array. Note though - this trick won't work inside of the `getUserChoice` function though - by that time, the array had been degraded to a pointer and the function has no way of telling how many items are in the array, unlike main - that's why I calculate the number there. Using a vector of strings would be much cleaner, since you could just pass a reference to the vector to the function, then inside the function you could call the `.size()` method of the vector to get the number of items it contains. Probably a little in front of where you're up to just now, hence the code in a similar style to your own.

Hope its helpful. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int getUserChoice(string *items, int numItems)
{
    int curSel = 0, textAttrib;
    bool selectionMade = false, needsUpdate = true; // we want to clearscreen first time through
    while (!selectionMade)
    {
        // only redraw the screen if something has changed, or we're on the first iteration of
        // our while loop.
        if (needsUpdate)
        {
            system("cls");
            needsUpdate = false;

            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
            cout << "(navigate with arrow keys, select with enter)" << endl << endl;
            for (int i=0; i<numItems; i++)
            {
                if (i == curSel)
                    textAttrib = 11;
                else
                    textAttrib = 15;

                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), textAttrib);

                if (i)
                    cout << " ";

                cout << items[i];
            }
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
        {
             curSel--;
             needsUpdate = true;
        }

        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
        {
             curSel++;
             needsUpdate = true;
        }

        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
            selectionMade = true;

        if (curSel < 0)
            curSel = numItems-1;
        else if (curSel > (numItems-1) )
            curSel = 0;
        Sleep(100);
    }
    char dummy[10];
    cin.getline(dummy, 10);   // clear the enter key from the kbd buffer
    return curSel;
}


int main()
{
    string Menu[] = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};

    int selection;
    selection = getUserChoice(Menu, sizeof(Menu)/sizeof(Menu[0]) );

    cout << "You chose: " << Menu[selection] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow! This is perfect for what I need! Especially because it's in a void function<3 But theres one problem, when I click enter for one of the 3 choices, a error comes up saying invalid null pointer! and I have no clue how to fix this. Also, out of the blue, is their any way to sum this code up a bit more? or is this the most compact you can get? Just seeing but this code is awesome man! Thank you for giving me the time out of your day. @enhzflep

Comment: Great! You're most welcome. (It's not actually a void function, for what it's worth - it returns a value and - so it's disqualified) Do you get the error with the code I've posted, or does the error come after making changes? (I tested the snippet first and can't think where any invalid null pointer error would occur) You should step-through it with the debugger to find the error. Can't really see how it could be made much shorter, to be honest.

Comment: Yeah, I get the error without even changing the code at all! and I have no clue why, what do you think I should do?

Comment: Here is the error I'm getting! I put it into a image uploaded.  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zegq2r&s=8#.VDnPH6UznwI

Comment: Forgot to add tags.. @enhzflep

Comment: Well, I just tried to build it with VS (I use MinGW generally) and I see what you mean. I hit abort, or whichever button it was that let me debug it. From there, the first thing I did was open the `Call Stack` window - this lets me see the sequence of function calls that led to the crash. The last line of (my) code to be run was my clearing of the enter key from the kbd buffer. Basically, it's complaining because I passed in NULL here: `cin.getline(NULL, 0);`. To fix, I added `char dummy[10];` immediately before, then used that buffer, i.e: `cin.getline(dummy, 10);`. I'll update the answer. :)

Comment: There we go! It works now! I have another question, how do i make it where i can make the output, so lets say if i choose rock. Rock = 0; I know how to do it, and you don't have to make any extra chars, but at the end where it says menu[selection] how do i clarify it so if rock is pressed, rock = 0; or something, also, how did you change it do make the text horizontal? just curious for i can learn in the future, and how would you make it vertical again? Learning in C++ is fun:) @enhzflep

Comment: :) - Not quite sure what you're asking, but I'll try. The `Menu` array has 3 elements, whose indexes ranges from 0 - 2. It's a matter of knowing that 0 corresponds to the first element of the array, which, in this case is "Rock". As for horiz layout - remember my first comment? The `endl` adds a new-line. You originally had one of them after each option, hence each option was on a new line. I removed that, printed a space before items 1 and 2 (but not 0), then finally printed a new-line character after I'd shown all 3 options. Don't forget to 'accept' the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: I accepted the answer! but just curious if you can still help me go a little further:) So would I putt like if(Menu[selection] == -2)cout << "Rock is chosen"; rock = 0; Would something like that work?

Comment: Sure. Actually, `if(selection==0) cout << "Rock is chosen";` By using `Menu[selection]` as I do, what I'm actually doing is getting the program to use the `selection` var as an index into the `Menu` array. This way, you don't need to keep track of which option has which index in the array. Though, you still need this information to work out who wins. I.e - if the cpu picks scissors (index 2), you know that if the user picks rock (index 0) then the cpu wins. Alternately, if the user picks paper (index 1) then the user wins. See what I'm getting at?

Comment: You are so helpful, like honestly! My Rock Paper Scissors game will be amazing. Thanks to you! I'll put your name in my credits! Just one last quick question if thats okay! I have this code.  void CPos(int i, int j)
{
     COORD cPos;
     cPos.X = j;
     cPos.Y = i;
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cPos);
 } it lets me change the position of text, how can I use it for the string menu? to make it lets say the bottom of the screen

Comment: actually I could just put a bunch of \n\n's infront of the first menu "rock", so nevermind forget that question! But like last thing because this kind of annoys me, if you look close at the text, why does it jitter? and is their a fix??:) @enhzflep

Comment: It jitters because you're clearing then re-drawing the screen about 7 times a second ( 1000ms / 150ms sleep). To get around this, you'd want to use a blocking function (one that doesn't return until done) to get keystrokes. You only need to redraw if the selection changes, yet the code refreshes 7 times a second regardless of the amount of activity. If you maintain a flag `needsUpdate`, you could set this to true in response to an arrow key. If this flag is true, then clear the screen and reset the flag. **EDIT:** use blocking input function, _or_ a flag. I'd go with a flag. :)

Comment: Like how would you even get started with doing that? It's sad to say that your helping me with a big chunk of my code! but in highschool, I'm in a C++ class and were not even that far and I'm honestly totally lost now! D: @enhzflep

Comment: Also, I just noticed, I'm going to have a DrawMap() function, but I need the scrolling text to the right of the map, in one of my comments above I showed how i changed the position, but how can i change the position of the string " Rock, Paper, Scissors"? @enhzflep

Comment: :big-grin: - No worries. I was in a similar position some 20-odd years ago. Have another look at the solution, I've altered it to include an update flag. You can see that the whole clear-screen / drawscreen block only runs if we need to update.

Comment: Not sure what the function is called, but you'd have to use the console functions to re-position the cursor before you print the string. You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx (Ahh, look into `SetCursorPosition`)

Comment: 20 years ago! You have to be a master at this language!:) Their is this weird problem now though, sorry If Im bugging you! If you want me to stop, just say it! You helped out enough already! But i entered this in my code just to see what was pressed     cout << "You chose: " << Menu[selection] << endl;
 if(selection == 0)
  system("CLS");
  cout << " Hey";
 if(selection == 1)
  system("CLS");
  cout << "heyo";
 if(selection == 2)
  system("CLS");
  cout << "heya"; no if i enter rock(selection == 1) it just all my hey, heyo, and heya, @ enhzflep

Comment: Nah, just ridden round the block once or twice. I started learning in high-school too. I think you forgot to put the `system("cls")` and the `cout << ...` inside curly braces. As you've written it, only the `cls` will run conditionally, while all 3 `cout`s will run regardless of choice. I.e `if (selection==0) {system("cls"); cout<<"Hey"; } else if (selection==1) {system("cls"); cout<<"Heyo"; } else if (selection==1) {system("cls"); cout<<"Heya"; }`. Better yet, clear the screen since all options do this anyway, then just print the right message. Less code, more clear, no need for the brackets.

Comment: I think it's great that highschools allow classes like C++, I might even take AP Java in Highschool next year! Now that code above sure did fix it:) But back to thee Set position for the string, I have this code. oid CPos(int i, int j) { COORD cPos; cPos.X = j; cPos.Y = i; SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cPos); } and it works for every cout I do! but how would you imply that code for a string? @enhzflep

Comment: I actually taught myself when consigned to the computer room for detention. :laughs: No real idea about how to go about using the function, I haven't programmed GUI type stuff in the console window for about 10 years or more.  I'll have to leave you to it for now I'm afraid. Bathurst is on and I wanna catch it (annual 1000km car-race here in aus). I tried to move this discussion to chat but you dont have enough rep. Chatting here in comments tends to annoy people - it's not really the place for it. You can email if you wish, I'll look later - my email adr is on my user-page. :)

Comment: Hey enhzflep, I did some research last night, now I did get where I can change the position of a string! I made a void where i am able to change the position and appreviate it to CPos( , ) like showed in this picture. This is what happens. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2woinmp&s=8#.VDr_ofldXGA It changes the first position of Play game! but then the rest, i have no clue where to go from then. On the left on my picture is the code and I highlighted in blue the area where i changed my string position, but how would I change the rest of the menu to allign with Play Game? @enhzflep

Comment: Gday mate. Sorry, forgot others cant see my email addr on my personal page. My provider is yahoo.com.au and my username is the same as my stack-overflow username. As for the location of stuff on the screen you show, it's a bit hard to tell what the problem is from the code visible in your screen-shot. The "\n\n\n\n" in one of your strings seems suspicious. You should really call your CPos function to position the cursor for the "Main Menu" text, rather than just advancing 4 lines. If you mail me the project, I'd be happy to have a look and suggest some further changes. :)

Comment: I think I sent it the the right email, just let me know if you got one! @ enhzflep